# How do I take apart an Apple iPod Connector?

Tags: usb, lightning

The cable, not the part on the actual iPod.

Comment: There are a few different variants of the iPod connector - the cable that came with my iPhone (and caught fire - another story!) was much smaller than the one for my iPod, even though it's the same connector. Having said that, I have no idea how to pull them apart...

Comment: As you don't specify what you want to do with it afterwards, a large hammer may do the trick.

Comment: Do you actually need to take it apart? or do you need a disassembled connector for some modding?

Answer (score 2):

*Joke: it's easy to take it apart. Do you need it to be usable afterwards?*

Thomas' suggestion is a good bet, but the pliers will likely damage the connector (the gray plastic).

But if you only care about the connector and not the housing (the white plastic), then you could cut the housing open without touching the connector itself.

It depends on what you want to do after you've taken it apart, but you don't mention that.

Answer (score 1):

I actually had an issue with mine where I wanted to take it apart as well. The Apple brand cables don't seem to be very well-suited for travel, as the wire has detached from the connector on a few of mine.

Anyway, it looks like you may be able to **CAREFULLY** take a pair of pliers and pull the connector out of the plastic molding (on the iDevice side, not USB). I haven't tried it, so I'm not sure...let me know what you think.

Dunno if you're still interested in this, but I came across [this one](http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product_info.php?products_id=9601) you can buy disassembled.